# Need help compiling .c file into shellcode

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, shellcode, objdump

I have a piece of code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char z[100] = "Hello world";

   printf("%s", z); 

   getchar(); 
}
```

I then compiled it using `gcc -S file.c`

Then I turned into a object file using: `gcc -c file.S -o file.o`

Then I turned into a exe to make sure it worked and it did using this: `gcc file.o -o file`

Next I moved on to dumping the object file to find the opcode using this: `objdump -d file.o`

I extracted the opcode and I got this:

```
\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x81\xec\x90
\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x48\xb8\x49\x20\x61\x6d\x20\x6c
\x65\x61\x48\xba\x72\x6e\x69\x6e
\x67\x20\x43\x20\x48\x89\x45\x90
\x48\x89\x55\x98\x48\xb8\x70\x72
\x6f\x67\x72\x61\x6d\x6d\x48\xba
\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x6c\x61\x6e\x67
\x48\x89\x45\xa0\x48\x89\x55\xa8
\x48\xb8\x75\x61\x67\x65\x2e\x00
\x00\x00\xba\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48
\x89\x45\xb0\x48\x89\x55\xb8\x48
\xc7\x45\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48
\xc7\x45\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48
\xc7\x45\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48
\xc7\x45\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48
\xc7\x45\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48
\xc7\x45\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7
\x45\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x8d
\x45\x90\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x8d\x0d
\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00
\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x48\x81\xc4\x90\x00
\x00\x00\x5d\xc3\x90\x90\x90\x90
```

Then I executed it using this

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char code[] = "\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x81\xec\x90\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xb8\x49\x20\x61\x6d\x20\x6c\x65\x61\x48\xba\x72\x6e\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x43\x20\x48\x89\x45\x90\x48\x89\x55\x98\x48\xb8\x70\x72\x6f\x67\x72\x61\x6d\x6d\x48\xba\x69\x6e\x67\x20\x6c\x61\x6e\x67\x48\x89\x45\xa0\x48\x89\x55\xa8\x48\xb8\x75\x61\x67\x65\x2e\x00\x00\x00\xba\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x89\x45\xb0\x48\x89\x55\xb8\x48\xc7\x45\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xc7\x45\xc8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xc7\x45\xd0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xc7\x45\xd8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xc7\x45\xe0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\xc7\x45\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc7\x45\xf0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x8d\x45\x90\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x8d\x0d\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x48\x81\xc4\x90\x00\x00\x00\x5d\xc3\x90\x90\x90\x90";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int foo_value = 0;

  int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;
  foo_value = foo();

  printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
```

Compiled that using `gcc shell.c`
Then I ran a.exe and it says:

```
1 [main] a 106 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to a.exe.stackdump
```

Comment: Also note the CPU will stop execution of your shellcode when a *nul* is encountered. so `"\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x81\xec\x90\x00"` is all that would be executed in your example.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about nul chars

Answer (score 3):

The machine code for `file` is not position-independent, and tries to call library functions.  This does not "just work" when turned into shellcode.

Single-step your `a.exe` in a debugger and see how it fails.

Also, you need to use `gcc -zexecstack shell.c` so the shellcode is in an executable page.

Comment: OP has placed his shell code into static storage, so making the stack executable should not change anything.

Comment: @fuz: `gcc -zexecstack` makes all sections/segments executable, including newly-allocated dynamic storage with `malloc`.  The "stack" name is unfortunate.

Comment: Thank you, I will check when i get time